# Minor spelling error in flagged question description

Tags: bug, design

There is a minor grammatical mistake in the description that shows up in the review queues:

[image: Flagged question commentary]

It should read

> "*This question doesn't meet **an** Arqade guideline.*"

Comment: How could I have missed that in all my years of reviewing...