# Minor spelling error in flagged question description, part II

Tags: bug, design

Shouldn't it be "**technical support *for* modded Minecraft**" in the description below?

[image]

(The title is a reference to [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/minor-spelling-error-in-flagged-question-description).)

Comment: Noted, we've been kinda meaning to get around to rewriting the close reasons using the new format so consider this [status-planned]